# Change values of timer using I2C

Tags: arduino-mega, i2c

I'd like to alter the "LED_T_ON" values using an I2C enabled device (i.e. RPi)

Code for Arduino Mega slave:

```
//slave

#include <Wire.h>

#define SLAVE_ADDRESS 0x08


const int PWR_LED = 43;
int LED_TinH_ON = 18;
int LED_T_ON = 5000;
int LED_T_OFF = 5000;


String inString = "";    // string to hold input
byte LastMasterCommand = 0;
int Mval;

char user_input;

class Relay {
  int relayPin;
  long OnTime;     // milliseconds of on-time
  long OffTime;    // milliseconds of off-time

  // These maintain the current state
  int relayState;                 // pumpState used to set the PUMP
  unsigned long previousMillis;   // will store last time PUMP was updated

  // Constructor - creates a Timer and initializes the member variables and state
  public:
  Relay(int pin, long on, long off)
  {
    relayPin = pin;
    pinMode(relayPin, OUTPUT);     

    OnTime = on;
    OffTime = off;

    relayState = LOW; 
    previousMillis = 0;  //ORIGINALLY 0
  }

  void Update()
  {
    // check to see if it's time to change the state of the TIMER
    unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

    if((relayState == HIGH) && (currentMillis - previousMillis >= OnTime))
    {
      relayState = LOW;  // Turn it off
      previousMillis = currentMillis;  // Remember the time
      digitalWrite(relayPin, relayState);  // Update the actual LED
    }
    else if ((relayState == LOW) && (currentMillis - previousMillis >= OffTime))
    {
      relayState = HIGH;  // turn it on
      previousMillis = currentMillis;   // Remember the time
      digitalWrite(relayPin, relayState);   // Update the actual RELAY
    }
  }
};

Relay relay3(PWR_LED, LED_T_OFF, LED_T_ON);

void setup() {
 // initialize serial communication with computer:
  Serial.begin(9600);

  Wire.begin(SLAVE_ADDRESS);

  Wire.onReceive(receiveData);
  Wire.onRequest(slavesRespond);

  pinMode(PWR_LED, OUTPUT);
}


void loop() {
  delay(1000);

  Serial.print("LED_T_ON=");
  Serial.println(LED_T_ON);
  Serial.print("LED_T_OFF=");
  Serial.println(LED_T_OFF);
  Serial.println();

  relay3.Update();

  switch (Mval) {
    case 1 ... 25:
      LED_TinH_ON = Mval;
      Serial.print("LED time on: ");
      Serial.print(LED_TinH_ON);
      Serial.println("h");
      LED_T_ON = LED_TinH_ON*1000;//*60*60;
      LED_T_OFF = (24-LED_TinH_ON)*1000;//*60*60;
    break;
  }
}


void receiveData(int byteCount) {
  LastMasterCommand = Wire.read();
  while (Wire.available()) {
    int msg = Wire.read();

    if (isDigit(msg)) {
      inString += (char)msg;
    }
  }
  Mval = inString.toInt();
  //Serial.println(LastMasterCommand);
  inString = "";
  //Serial.println(Mval);
}

void slavesRespond() {
}
```

When I change the value on the RPi the Arduino receives and displays the correct value but the timed relays don't actually use the updated values.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I see nothing there relating to I2C. What there can be "displaying the correct value" when there is neither anything receiving a value nor anything displaying anything anywhere?

Comment: Same. Also LED_T_ON is not changed anywhere (nor is OnTime).

Comment: My bad, edited to display the right code

Comment: assuming maybe you have other code that is doing the I2C bit, if that code is changing the value of LED_T_ON that will have no effect on that relay object as that value is passed in during the construction. You would need to update relay3.OnTime    ( your order/naming is also switched, relay3(PWR_LED, LED_T_OFF, LED_T_ON); calls Relay(int pin, long on, long off)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your updating `LED_T_ON` and `LED_T_OFF` but those values were already passed into the constructor and changing them will not change the object. you need to update  `relay3.OnTime` and `relay3.OffTime`